# Why is this float('20200407_2') allowed in Python3.6?

Tags: python

Does anyone understand why Python 3.6 allows this string `'20200407_2'` code to be converted?

```
>>> float('20200407_2')
202004072.0
```

Python 2.7 does not allow it.

```
>>> float('20200407_2')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 20200407_2
```

Comment: Because underscores are now allowed in numeric literals, to make e.g. `1_000_000` (or `10_00_000`, depending on where you're from) easier to read: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0515/

Comment: Wow that is going to be weird to see code like `12_1 + 2_3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float):

> Changed in version 3.6: Grouping digits with underscores as in code literals is allowed.

I think it answers your question.